# Angular universal/Server side rendering missing files

Tags: angular-cli

I'm trying to make my angular app to ssr, in the [official documentation](https://angular.io/guide/universal) it says that I should run

`webpack --config webpack.server.config.js --progress --colors`

But I can't get it to compile correctly:

```
ERROR in ./server.ts
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './server/main' in '/home/lucaswxp/reduza/reduza-angular'
 @ ./server.ts 18:9-33
```

Line with problem:

```
const { AppServerModuleNgFactory, LAZY_MODULE_MAP } = require('./server/main');
```

These files are supposed to be created dynamically, that's why they are required with "require", but there's no "server/main.js" file in the dist folder anywhere, this is what I got in the dist folder:

```
out-tsc/
   e2e/
   src/
   node_modules/
reduza-ui/ <-- my project name
   main.08ht283hg20s3.js
server.js
server.js.map
```

And my angular.json config:

```
"server": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:server",
          "options": {
            "outputPath": "dist/reduza-ui",
            "main": "src/server.main.ts",
            "tsConfig": "src/server.tsconfig.app.json"
          },
          "configurations": {
            "stable": {
              "optimization": true,
              "outputHashing": "all",
              "sourceMap": false,
              "namedChunks": false,
              "extractLicenses": true,
              "vendorChunk": false,
              "fileReplacements": [
                { 
                  "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                  "with": "src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        }
```

There's no "server" folder. I can't figure what did I miss?
I tried including manually the file `dist/reduza-ui/main.08ht283hg20s3.js`, this compiled, but I got the following error acessing `localhost:4000`:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'moduleType' of undefined
    at /home/lucaswxp/reduza/reduza-angular/dist/server.js:151:1457
    at e.invoke (/home/lucaswxp/reduza/reduza-angular/dist/server.js:1809:7001)
    at Object.onInvoke (/home/lucaswxp/reduza/reduza-angular/dist/server.js:137:1986)
    at e.invoke (/home/lucaswxp/reduza/reduza-angular/dist/server.js:1809:6941)
    at t.run (/home/lucaswxp/reduza/reduza-angular/dist/server.js:1809:2171)
    at e.run (/home/lucaswxp/reduza/reduza-angular/dist/server.js:137:2710)
    at e.bootstrapModuleFactory (/home/lucaswxp/reduza/reduza-angular/dist/server.js:151:1388)
    at md (/home/lucaswxp/reduza/reduza-angular/dist/server.js:1673:888)
    at p.engine (/home/lucaswxp/reduza/reduza-angular/dist/server.js:1794:10074)
    at p.render (/home/lucaswxp/reduza/reduza-angular/dist/server.js:1984:1029)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an error in the documentation.

Their documentation's code is

```
const { AppServerModuleNgFactory, LAZY_MODULE_MAP } = require('./server/main');
```

However, this not correct, or at least not very clear.

#### Point 1: You should not build in production mode.

Although you see at one line in the documentation that they want you to include in the scripts section of your package.json a line like

```
ng run my-project:server:production
```

You shouldn't do that, for two reasons: First, their instruction to change the angular.json does not include the production build. Second, the production build (if you just copied from the production of your actual non-server app) is made in a way to include a hash in the filename, which leads to a file named like `main.a220df2.js`. This of course is not ideal, as this would mean you have to change your server.ts all the time.

So, either disable hashing `"outputHashing": "none"` or simply don't do a production build by calling `ng run my-project:server` (simply remove `:production`).

#### Point 2: Use correct `require`

The actual require() call should point to your built `main.server.ts`, which is references in your `angular.json` under the section `projects:PROJECTNAME:architect:server`. The documentation has defined the outputPath as `"outputPath": "dist/my-project-server",`, which means we have a file in `dist/my-project-server/main.js` laying around (take care of point 1 first and disable outputHashing or don't build in production mode at all). 
Exactly this file needs to be `require`d in your `server.ts`.

So, in your case, it's the file `./dist/reduza-ui/main.js` you should include, once your have disabled outputHasing or stopped building in production mode.

```
const { AppServerModuleNgFactory, LAZY_MODULE_MAP } = require('./dist/reduza-ui/main');
```

An additional tip: At the very top of the documentation, you see a link to the complete code of the whole article: https://angular.io/generated/zips/universal/universal.zip. There you can see what the real code should look like.

### Two last tip to get it fully working:

### First

The documentation says in server.ts something like:

```
const template = readFileSync(join(DIST_FOLDER, 'browser', 'index.html')).toString();
```

The `browser` is the actual default version of your app, so your regular build. If you do `ng build` you end up having a folder in `dist/` that is your actual default app. This app is meant by `browser`. In your case you named your server version `reduza-ui`, so maybe your actual app is named `reduza-ui-default` in dist. In server.ts needs to be `'reduza-ui-default'` instead of `'browser'` on several places.

### Second

At this point, when you compiled your server, started it, and requested your first page in your browser, you get in your console:

```
StaticInjectorError(Platform: core)[InjectionToken Application Initializer -> InjectionToken DocumentToken]:
  Right-hand side of 'instanceof' is not an object
```

This is because webpack minimizes your server.ts. Disable that using

```
optimization: {
    minimize: false
},
```

in `webpack.server.config.js`.

Comment: Thank you! I actually managed to get it working by setting up a new project from their skeleton sample. But it's good to know this kind of info, thank you.

Comment: I have this error: "Right-hand side of 'instanceof' is not an object" because i'm trying to minimize server.js. I'm trying this because TTFB is too long (6sec). I suspect that's the reason: server.js is 300k lines. Is that the cause?

Comment: @Becario Senior you should try to do a production build and disable hashing instead. 6sec sounds like there's something wrong. It should never take that long.